# "/journal" partition size for dedicated MongoDB server (in relation to OS partition size)

Tags: linux, mongodb, filesystems, database-partitioning

We are setting up a new dedicated Linux MongoDB server.

In [a relevant blog post about the topic](https://www.mongodb.com/blog/post/performance-best-practices-hardware-and-os-configuration) on the MongoDB blog, it is stated that:

> We recommend storing MongoDB's journal files on a separate disk
> partition.

The blog and [the official documentation](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/manual/administration/production-notes/) (also [here](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/manual/administration/production-checklist-operations/) and [here](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/manual/faq/storage/)) provide details about RAM, storage and filesystem type requirements and other storage-related configuration options -- but makes no mention of the expected journal sizes when using WiredTiger (that it recommends using). In addition, it is unclear whether the the storage recommendations only apply to the OS partition on which MongoDB is run - or whether it applies to the partition to be mounted as the main journal partition, too.

It is my understanding that the *journal* partition could potentially need to be much larger than the main OS (or root-mounted (or"/") partition), even if the OS is set up to mainly run MongoDB.

E.g, if the drive has a total capacity of 50GB, then it might be considered optimal to allocate only 5 GB to the OS partition, but 45GB to the MongoDB "journal" partition... I cannot find clear documentation on this matter currently.

I would appreciate being pointed to a relevant resource of information, or if someone could share any practical experience that may serve as guidance?

Comment: Nowadays computers are often virtualized and you run network storage. Thus such statements do not look so relevant anymore.